# Outlook Autformat rules VBA empty filter

Tags: vba, outlook

I try to automatically add **Autoformat Rules** under OUTLOOK 2013.

**The rule is created... but the filter is empty !!**

This is my code :

```
Dim objView As TableView
Dim objRule As AutoFormatRule
If Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView.ViewType = olTableView Then
    Set objView = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView
    Set objRule = objView.AutoFormatRules.Add("myRule")
    With objRule
        .Filter = """urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE 'gmail.com%'"
        With .Font
            .Name = "Courier New"
            .Size = "8"
            .Bold = True
            .Color = olColorBlue
        End With
    End With
    objView.Save
    objView.Apply
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to **Enable** the rule, and you can also try to replace special characters using the `Chr()` function :

```
Sub test_Vincent()
Dim r As String, _
    r2 As String, _
    r3 As String

r = """urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE 'gmail.com%'"
r2 = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname" & Chr(34) & " LIKE 'gmail.com%'"
r3 = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname" & Chr(34) & " LIKE " & Chr(39) & "gmail.com%" & Chr(39)

MsgBox r & vbCrLf & r2 & vbCrLf & r3
End Sub
```

Here is your amended code :

```
Sub Full_Vincent()

Dim objView As TableView, _
    objRule As AutoFormatRule

If Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView.ViewType <> olTableView Then
Else
    Set objView = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView
    Set objRule = objView.AutoFormatRules.Add("myRule")
    With objRule
        .Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname" & Chr(34) & " LIKE " & Chr(39) & "gmail.com%" & Chr(39)
        .Enabled = True
        With .Font
            .Name = "Courier New"
            .Size = "8"
            .Bold = True
            .Color = olColorBlue
        End With
    End With
    objView.Save
    objView.Apply
End If

    Set objView = Nothing
    Set objRule = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your repply ! Nothing more appear, criteria still empty... !!

Comment: It's a known issue, outlook is not saving AutoFormatRule.Filter property (when using it from code, UI works fine). https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b4a0cf8-dba9-417a-94c3-7be4340a5961/outlook-2010-autoformatrulefilter-property-not-saving?forum=outlookdev

Comment: So would it be possible to export the manually created view to another user profile ?